# When retrieving Names from Contacts only the last person in my Contact is Retrieved all others are null

Tags: java, android, contacts

Like the title says Here when retrieving Names from Contacts only the last person in my Contact is Retrieved all others are null. Below is my get contacts method that is called

```
private void getContacts(){
    Activity a = getActivity();
    ArrayList<Contact> cList = new ArrayList<>();

    if(a !=null){
        ContentResolver cr = a.getContentResolver();

        Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER};
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null );

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int hasNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if(hasNumber>0){
                    contact = new Contact(id, fName, mName, lName, phone, userImage);
                    int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
                    id = cursor.getString(idIndex);
                    contact.setId(id);


                    String[] nameProj = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME};
                    Cursor nameCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, nameProj, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact.getId()}, null);

                    while(nameCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        int fNameColumnIndex = nameCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
                        int mNameColumnIndex = nameCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME);
                        int lNameColumnIndex = nameCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME);

                        fName = nameCursor.getString(fNameColumnIndex);
                        mName = nameCursor.getString(mNameColumnIndex);
                        lName = nameCursor.getString(lNameColumnIndex);

                        contact.setFirstName(fName);
                        contact.setMiddleName(mName);
                        contact.setLastName(lName);
                        Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.valueOf(id));
                        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, photoUri);
                        userImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        contact.setUserImage(userImage);
                        Log.i("LISST", contact.getFirstName() + "");

                    }
                    nameCursor.close();

                    String[] phoneProj = {Phone.NUMBER};
                    Cursor phoneCursor = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, phoneProj, Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    while(phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        int phoneIndex = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                        phone = phoneCursor.getString(phoneIndex);
                        contact.setPhoneNumber(phone);

                    }




                    cList.add(contact);
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }


            }

        }

        cursor.close();

        ListView lv = getView().findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(new ContactsAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.cell_layout,cList));

    }

}
```

Im doing all of this inside of a Fragment when printing the first names in the Log this is my result. It seems like its skipping the first two items and stopping on the last contact in my list

```
2020-10-11 20:50:40.507 9459-9459/com.example.belardocarlos_ce04 I/LISST: 2
2020-10-11 20:50:40.514 9459-9459/com.example.belardocarlos_ce04 I/LISST: Carlos
2020-10-11 20:50:40.523 9459-9459/com.example.belardocarlos_ce04 I/LISST: null
2020-10-11 20:50:40.565 9459-9459/com.example.belardocarlos_ce04 I/LISST: 2
2020-10-11 20:50:40.572 9459-9459/com.example.belardocarlos_ce04 I/LISST: Benecio
2020-10-11 20:50:40.577 9459-9459/com.example.belardocarlos_ce04 I/LISST: null
2020-10-11 20:50:40.594 9459-9459/com.example.belardocarlos_ce04 I/LISST: 2
2020-10-11 20:50:40.599 9459-9459/com.example.belardocarlos_ce04 I/LISST: Marta
```

Comment: Instead of GIVEN_NAME try DISPLAY_NAME.

Comment: Im looking to use the given name since im putting those values into an object